# Retrieve user ID from conversation with slack bot

Tags: python, bots, slack, slack-api, amazon-lex

I'm trying to get the slack UserId of the user who initiated a conversation with a bot.

I tried using users.identity scope and api, but I'm only getting the UserId  of the user who created the bot. The bot will be used by multiple users so I want to have an isolated chat for each user by getting the exact UserId of the user who is currently having a conversation with the bot.

I'm using Python, Amazon Lex and Slack.

Can somebody point me to the right path?

Answer (score 0):

If the conversation is initiated as a direct message with the bot, you can subscribe to [`message.im`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im) event. You'll receive this event every time a user sends a message to the bot. In the response JSON body, `event.user` should provide you the userId.

It could be a different solution depending upon how you are making the app, and where do you need this information.

Comment: Hi Jai, Thanks for responding. Does this approach needs RTM or Events API? For now, I'm just using a module (requests module in Python) that directly use post.Message to the initiate a live chat on the bot. I'm wondering how can I retrieve such response.

Comment: The approach I described uses events API. In your case, how does the user initiate a conversation? Does she send a DM to the bot user? If so, events API would be a good solution. Also have a look at the official [Python client][1] made by Slack.

[1]: https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/